# How to create a xls file in titanium appcelerator?

Tags: javascript, excel, titanium, appcelerator, commonjs

I have to send a report in xls format in my application.
And it's costly for me to create an API to receive the data and send the xls.
I tried to use some code but all of them is in node.js, and I can't find a CommonJs(module, plugin, etc) for create the xls.

Can someone help me to create the xls in titanium?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which libraries you've tested. This might be one to try out: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

But does it really need to be a xls file? If you don't need any styling or special features you could create a cvs file and send this. Excel will open them and display rows/columns just fine.

And if it has to be a XSL file you really should look at a server side implementation e.g. with https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel. For the "API" you could just call an URL with GET parameters to pass the data (if it doesn't have to be secure)